# Dashboard left hand menu overlapping next item down

Tags: menus, admin, dashboard

Stuck with this one and wondered if someone could point me in the right direction... we updated one of our wordpress sites a couple of weeks ago and only revisited it today and noticed that the Dashboard menu down the left hand side had a bit of a bug only affecting this one site...

The menu items when rolled over with the mouse move back up into place / or if I do a refresh to another page it will sometimes sort itself out.

I've removed/uploaded wp-includes & wp-admin folders from fresh download of Wordpress 4.2.2

I've disabled all plugins

There are no inspector errors or missing scripts..

Thanks in advance.

[image: Wordpress Dashboard Menu]

Comment: A test I should've done first was another browser, working fine in Safari, just broken in my version of Chrome...

Comment: Exactly the same problem. Chrome Version 45.0.2453.0 m (64-bit) on windows 8.1. Other browsers work fine. What is your version of Chrome?

Comment: @FrankP.Walentynowicz - glad I am not the only one - Chrome Version 45.0.2453.0 dev (64-bit)

Comment: What theme are you using? Have you tried using Twenty Fifteen? Does the problem still exist?

Comment: @mrwweb - tried all themes, new installation, locally and server - disabled all chrome extensions - just a strange Chrome issue :(

Comment: Ok. More troubleshooting steps: 1) Update to WordPress 4.3. 2) Are you using an AdBlocker or scriptblocker browser add-on? Try disabling that. Try disabling all browser add-ons. 3) Pay attention to which screens display the error and see if only certain screens display the error.

Comment: @mrwweb - tried it all, even again this morning, freshly downloaded copy from wordpress - stock theme, no extensions - no script blocker - no strange scripts - no errors in the inspector - the strange menu bug even happens when I collapse the menu (so it's the thin strip) - however, the responsive burger menu works fine... if I goto inspect an element and try and alter a CSS rule the menu goes back to normal - disabling javascript stops the weird bug, but I don't know how to diagnose a javascript problem :(