# Corrupt WordPress Design/Appearance

Tags: sidebar, design

Has anyone ever experienced the following in terms of sidebar design corruption.

This has only recently started happening, using the vanilla WordPress package from the site.

I've tried multiple browsers and variables and still this seems to be persisting. It's also causing XML imports to hang and never finish, as well as a few other issues that give the impression that the WordPress installation is not stable.

[image: Design/Appearance Fault]

Comment: There are multiple posts on this already - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/194336/49852 and http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/196667/49852 - what browser are you using by default? It appears to be a consistent Chrome issue for some people. Which 'multiple' browsers are you using? :)

Comment: Hi Aravona,Thanks for your response! Well thus far i've been using Safari and Mozilla, however haven't had a chance to test on a Windows VM. Do you believe this could be the root cause of this issue? Judging by the other threads you kindly provided.

Comment: If it's a cross browser issue then I can't inherently say what's wrong, if it were one browser it'd be most likely to be a browser issue.

Comment: This is an issue with Google Chrome. The current fix is to disable Slimming Paint as [Otto42's Suggestion](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33199#comment:45)

Answer (score 1):

See this thread: [WordPress admin menu formatting issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/195291/wordpress-admin-menu-formatting-issue/198300#198300) - there's a link there to download a plugin I wrote to temporarily work around the Chrome bug (which is what this is).